# Android Studio .gitignore file works in Mac OS X but not in Windows 7

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gitignore

I am using this .gitignore file in Mac OS X for my Android Studio project:

```
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
```

That works just fine there, but I have started using a Windows based machine where it seems this gitignore file is being ignored:

[image: Files not ignored]

Any ideas why this is happening?

I have tried to modify forward slashes for back slashes, as Windows and Mac OS X represent paths in different ways, but it didn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What makes you think it is being ignored? I do not see any files in your screenshot that are specified in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Do you have the .gitignore file in the same directory as where you called git init or git clone?

Comment: Then, if the project's got the same files and the .gitignore is not being ignored why I get those files to commit? @DavidDeutsch

Comment: Perhaps those files are generated on the Windows box, but not on the Mac?

Comment: Perhaphs. But I thought the files will be the same in both OS. Any idea of which lines shall I add to the .gitignore file? @DavidDeutsch

Comment: I have tried adding this two lines to the ignore file:
`/.idea/*`
`*.iml`
But still doesn't work